# Style and js doesn't work after changing project entry point to public folder

Tags: javascript, php, css, .htaccess

The project was working fine till i moved `index.php` from project root to `public` folder then moved css and js from `public` to `assets` folder
here is how my project looks like now

- public

  - index.php
- assets

  - css

    - style.css
  - js

    - main.js
      -.htaccess

i loaded the server with `php -S localhost:8000`

i get

```
Not Found

The requested resource / was not found on this server.
```

ignoring my .htaccess completely ! i even tried solutions like 
`AllowOverride All`
but still doesn't work
so i typed 
`php -S localhost:8000 -t public`
now site loads but css/js doesn't work at all even inline style ! 
when i open console i get

```
The script from “http://localhost:8000/assets/js/main.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type

Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:8000/assets/js/main.js”
```

any ideas ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.htaccess is a configuration file for use on web servers running the Apache Web Server software. It means that when you start project with `php -S localhost:8000` it simply ignores the routes written there.

What you can do:

1. Install Apache into your machine and configure your local server (will require some effort but you'll have the same setup as on the live environment)
2. Run `php -S localhost:8000` inside `public` folder or using `-t` option to set the document root (will work for simple relative paths but not when you want to use Apache specific features like `ModRewrite`)

Good luck with your web development journey!

Comment: i tried to use apache but it didn't read .htaccess either. When i change the root from `var/www/html` to `/var/www/html/project` that's the only way it uses the .htaccess and redirect my requests to public folder .. then i face the same problem with styling so i'm thinking the way i configured apache is the reason all this is failing!

Comment: i even deleted (apache/php) and reinstalled them again thinking they might cause the problem

Comment: here is my .htaccess content
https://gist.github.com/MagedAhmad/496c82c1e0b01f7b9516ecedde74ae4b

Answer (score 0):

In index.php file do the below changes

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../assets/css/style.css">

<script src="../assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: styles are not working at all even if in the head i typed <style> body { background-red; } </style> ... nothing happens !